# Why is my if statement not working right?

Tags: java, android

I have an if statement in the `onClick` listener for 2 buttons and it's  working fine when I only press one button but when I press the other I think that the if functions are interfering with each other, so I added a Log in order to know which methods is being called but everything is being called correctly, I tried everything I know of in order to fix this error but I can't.

Here is what should happen: I have 2 buttons (settings, store)when I press the settings button it views a `settingsLayout(LinearLayout)` with an animation and if I press the same button again it removes the `settingsLayout(LinearLayout)` with animation also, and if I press the store button it removes the visible `settingsLayout(LinearLayout)` and views `storeLayout(LinearLayout)` with animation, and when I press the store button it removes the visible `storeLayout(LinearLayout)`.

Here is what happens: after I press the store button then the settings (or vise versa) when I press any of the buttons to remove the visible layout, one of the layouts which is already Gone appears and then both disappear with animation.

Here is my code:

P.S the `if(visible)` checks if the buttons are visible or not

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.store:
            if(visible){
                if(!storeVisible){
                    Log.e("MSG", "If !storeVisible called");
                    if(settingsVisible){
                        setViewGone(settingsLayout);
                        settingsVisible = false;
                        setViewVisible(storeLayout);
                        storeVisible = true;
                    Log.e("MSG", "If !storeVisible and settingsVisible called");
                        return;
                    } else {
                        setViewVisible(storeLayout);
                        storeVisible = true;
                    Log.e("MSG", "If !storeVisible and else called");
                        return;
                    }
                } else if (storeVisible) {
                    settingsLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    setViewGone(storeLayout);
                    storeVisible = false;
                    Log.e("MSG", "else if storeVisible called");
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                store.setClickable(false);
                    Log.e("MSG", "else clickable called");
            }
            break;
        case R.id.settings:
            if(visible){
                if(!settingsVisible){
                    Log.e("MSG", "If !settingsVisible called");
                    if(storeVisible){
                        setViewGone(storeLayout);
                        storeVisible = false;
                        setViewVisible(settingsLayout);
                        settingsVisible = true;
                    Log.e("MSG", "If !settingsVisible and storeVisible called");
                        return;
                    } else {
                        setViewVisible(settingsLayout);
                        settingsVisible = true;
                    Log.e("MSG", "If !settingsVisible and else called");
                        return;
                    }
                } else if (settingsVisible) {
                    storeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    setViewGone(settingsLayout);
                    settingsVisible = false;
                    Log.e("MSG", "else if settingsVisible called");
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                settings.setClickable(false);
                    Log.e("MSG", "else clickable called");
            }
            break;
    }
}

public void setViewVisible(View view){
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    view.startAnimation(expandTop);
}

public void setViewGone(View view){
    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    view.startAnimation(retractTop);
}
```

Comment: what is `if(visible){` what it does?

Comment: @Siva it checks if the buttons are visible or not

Comment: that one is the issue...every time you are checking visibility of both buttons.. in any case check only the visibility of the button that you are operating... change the code and check now

Comment: @Siva they are a group of buttons not that 2 only, and they all are either visible or not there can't be a visible button while the other is not visible

Comment: It means all will be visible at a time or all won't be visible at a time... can you add screenshot

Comment: @Siva that is what it means

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
if(visible){
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.store:

                if(!storeVisible){
                    Log.e("MSG", "If !storeVisible called");
                    if(settingsVisible){
                        setViewGone(settingsLayout);
                        settingsVisible = false;
                        setViewVisible(storeLayout);
                        storeVisible = true;
                    Log.e("MSG", "If !storeVisible and settingsVisible called");
                        return;
                    } else {
                        setViewVisible(storeLayout);
                        storeVisible = true;
                    Log.e("MSG", "If !storeVisible and else called");
                 settingsLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    setViewGone(storeLayout);
                    storeVisible = false;
                    Log.e("MSG", "else if storeVisible called");
                    return;

                    }
                } 
            } else {
                store.setClickable(false);
                    Log.e("MSG", "else clickable called");
            }
            break;
        case R.id.settings:
               if(!settingsVisible){
                    Log.e("MSG", "If !settingsVisible called");
                    if(storeVisible){
                        setViewGone(storeLayout);
                        storeVisible = false;
                        setViewVisible(settingsLayout);
                        settingsVisible = true;
                    Log.e("MSG", "If !settingsVisible and storeVisible called");
                        return;
                    } else {
                        setViewVisible(settingsLayout);
                        settingsVisible = true;
                    Log.e("MSG", "If !settingsVisible and else called");
              storeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    setViewGone(settingsLayout);
                    settingsVisible = false;
                    Log.e("MSG", "else if settingsVisible called");
                    return;

                    }
                } 
            } else {
                settings.setClickable(false);
                    Log.e("MSG", "else clickable called");
            }
            break;
    }


public void setViewVisible(View view){
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    view.startAnimation(expandTop);
}

public void setViewGone(View view){
    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    view.startAnimation(retractTop);
}
```

Comment: changed the logic..try once...check for syntax once I don't have exlipse right now.